# How to link to android app with Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I have a free version of app and i want to link the app store on click of the buy button on the app. How to i do this, i have completely no idea and please help me with some code.
Thanks in advance

What I did was

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buybutton);

    buyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=app name"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this code to redirect user to the market:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=your.game.package.name"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot egor but i did try with that it did not work, what i need to do is when i click on buy button, it has to take me to the mark and find my app . how many classes do i need for this.. please help me.. thanks again

Comment: @user896340, Did you try this on a real device or on an emulator?

Comment: @user896340, Of course, there is no Android Market on the emulator, so the only way to test this is to use a real device. And also you won't be able to see your app on the market until you publish, I think it's clear.

Comment: Egor, i am creating a search activity, what i want to do is i want to reduce the length of the edit text to 3/4 of the screen once i type the text in the edit text. before typing the size would be fill parent. Help me with some code

Comment: @user896340, You should create a new question or find the answer in an existing question

Answer (score 5):

use below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=your_package_name"));
startActivity(intent);
```

refer this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Comment: thanks llango but i tried with the same code but then i get a error message saying that no activity found, please help a bit of steps on doing the same. Thanks again

Comment: are you running in mobile or emulator?

Comment: i am running it on emulator but will be tested on mobile

Comment: if you run in emulator sure it will show error, because emulator doesn't have android market. You should run in mobile only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the MainActivity, you can use:

```
MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=YourPackageName")));
```

But if you are a Fragment, is important add Flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" in your intent, like this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=YourPackageName"));
startActivity(intent);
```

if you need to know your package name, you can verify it in your manifests file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="Here"
android:versionCode="40"
android:versionName="6.7">
```