# How do i link my app to market on app store

Tags: android, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to link to android app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144283/how-to-link-to-android-app-store)

I want to link my app to the app store market, how could i do it. i have no idea about it..

please find the little code that i did for doing it

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        buyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buybutton);

        buyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=app name"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Instead of "app_name" there should be your app's package name, then this will work.

Answer (score 4):

I do it like this:

```
 Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+getPackageName()));
 startActivity(marketIntent);
```

Which is the same as:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+getPackageName()));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is not working for me. It is giving me error

01-14 22:27:31.040: E/AndroidRuntime(463): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.helloOne.Launcher }

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

// Search application

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:package name");  
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);  
startActivity(it);
```

//show application's detail page

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=package name"));
startActivity(intent);
```

### Update:

For your information, these all information are given here in Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent , by this article you will be more clear about displaying detail page of any application and to perform searching operation by passing various criterias like developer name, package name, etc.